# Kubernetes cannot access service through clusterIP

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-service

I have created 1 deployment (I am using minikube)

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: mydeployments
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: # tells the controller which pods to watch/belong to
    matchLabels:
      name: deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      name: testpod1
      labels:
        name: deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: c00
          image: httpd
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

and one service

```
kind: Service # Defines to create Service type Object
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: demoservice
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80 # Containers port exposed
      targetPort: 80 # Pods port
  selector:
    name: deployment # Apply this service to any pods which has the specific label, this shoudl mach with your deployment that you have created
  type: ClusterIP # Specifies the service type i.e ClusterIP or NodePort, this is the default service. Within the cluster. Next is nodeport then loadbalancer
```

here is the pod ip address and its port

```
IP:               172.17.0.5
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.5
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mydeployments-84c5754d58
Containers:
  c00:
    Container ID:   docker://bda97868c71993b12a5087a45aed7fe2217850e6f2ad5fb2830be9e4fae8b7fb
    Image:          httpd
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://httpd@sha256:71e882df50adc606c57e46e5deb3c933288e2c7775472a639326d9e4e40a47c2
    Port:           80/TCP
```

when I exec into the the pod and run curl command it works

```
root@mydeployments-84c5754d58-l7g9q:/usr/local/apache2# curl 172.17.0.5:80
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

and here is the ClusterIP ip address

```
demoservice      ClusterIP      10.99.55.212    <none>        80/TCP         20h
```

but when I run the curl command it does nothing and even if I paste this ip address along with the port **10.99.55.212:80** it does not work

Comment: From outside to reach application port the service should be of node port or load balancer type.  Cluster IP is meant only for internal k8s communication. That  where exec into the pod and curl command works.

Comment: Based on the description, it looks like the second CURL command is also run inside the POD

Comment: Are you running this in Minikube ?

Comment: @LWimsey yes I am running Minikube

Comment: I assume you're using a shell within a pod, unless there is any netpols that block the traffic you could try to connect with the dns name: <svc>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local

However this is for normal clusters and I'm not sure about minikube, you can just try <svc>.<namespace> and it should work as well.

Comment: I have experienced the same problem with Minikube.. When  connecting from inside a POD to a service that includes the same POD, it cannot connect to itself.
This is strange because Minikube performs source NAT, so it should just work fine.
On a real cluster, I have not seen this problem even though the logic was more complicated.. ie. kube-proxy did not apply/implement source NAT, except when the selected destination was the same POD where the request originated from. Perhaps it is a limitation of Minikube

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: my issue is not resolved because technical it is not possible to access a service from outside when you are running minikube

Comment: As you are saying that there are no such options, what are the steps you are following to overcome this issue?

Comment: is there any option to access service from outside when you are running minikube? if yes then which one?